# Is there a way to declare executables with hyphens in a OCaml dune?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I'm setting up a demo project using dune, and want to name the executable "hello-world.exe" instead of "hello_world". If I try to build the project I get an compiler error. How can I declare an executable with hyphens in the filename?

I'm using dune 1.9.3 and OCaml 4.05.0.

dune:

```
(executable
 (name hello-world))
```

hello-world.ml

```ml
let () = print_endline "Hello, World!"
```

build error

```sh
$ dune build hello-world.exe
Info: creating file dune-project with this contents:
| (lang dune 1.9)

      ocamlc .hello-world.eobjs/byte/hello-world.{cmi,cmo,cmt} (exit 2)
(cd _build/default && /usr/bin/ocamlc.opt -w @a-4-29-40-41-42-44-45-48-58-59-60-40 -strict-sequence -strict-formats -short-paths -keep-locs -g -bin-annot -I .hello-world.eobjs/byte -no-alias-deps -opaque -o .hello-world.eobjs/byte/hello-world.cmo -c -impl hello-world.ml)
File "hello-world.ml", line 1:
Warning 24: bad source file name: "Hello-world" is not a valid module name.
File "hello-world.ml", line 1:
Error: Some fatal warnings were triggered (1 occurrences)
```

Comment: Using `public_name` perhaps? See https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dune-files.html#executable. Or you could just rename it afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

You need to disable the warning 24:

```
(executable (name hello-world) (flags (:standard -w -24)))
```

or just

```
(executable (name hello-world) (flags (:standard -warn-error -24)))
```

if you prefer to keep the warning